# Understanding android:launchMode

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack, launchmode

I'm getting really confused about the different activity launchModes in Android. I understand it has something to do with the activity stack which is also something not so clear to me. I would appreciate a short explanation about each launchMode with a simple use case.

Comment: i think the following is a good point to start: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode

Answer (score 2):

```
SingleTask and SingleInstance activities can only begin a task. They are always at the 
root of the activity stack. Moreover, the device can hold only one instance of the 
activity at a time — only one such task.
```

[More Details](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Standard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SingleTop"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SingleTask"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity="" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SingleInstance"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" />      <!--//TODO launchMode -->

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

[Sample Demo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SRmR-s41C_xDb8JuCVXtXslRW4BQpNWt)

Answer (score 0):

Android 4 types of launch mode:-
1.Standard
2.Single Top
3.Single Task
4.Single Instance

1. **Standard** -> When go to Activity A to activity B then new object create every time and when go back press go back multiple times.
2. **Single Top** -> when user to Activity A to activity B and again go Activity B
   then new instance not create and onCreate Method not call. but  onNewIntent method
   call.
3. **Single Task** ->  when user to Activity A to activity B and acitivity B to activity C again go Activity B then new instance not create and onCreate Method not call. but  onNewIntent method call. and when backpress on activity B then go to activity A. Activity C is remove from mid.
4. **Single Instance**  -> Activity Stack B is A to B to C. After launching the B activity,
   A -> B -> C -> D — Job #1
   B — Job #2 (Here, B will be assigned to a separate duty)

If you continue like this and add E and B, the stack will look like this: Job #1— A -> C -> D -> E.
5. List item